# Populating a select form by iterating through an object

Tags: forms, reactjs, materialize

Attempting to populate a select form using an object I'm passing to my component as a prop. The object looks like this: `{24: {14: 64.99, 20: 89.99, 26: 114.99}, 30: {14: 74.99, 20: 99.99, 26: 124.99}` and I'm attempting to isolate the `24` and the `30` as values in my form. Here's the relevant code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Input } from 'react-materialize';

class HeightPicker extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      height: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({height: e.target.value});
    }

  displayHeights(){
    let prices = this.props.prices;
    let height;
    let heights = [];
    console.log(prices);
    for (height in prices) {
      heights.push(height)
    };
    console.log(heights);
    heights.forEach(function(h) {
      return(<option value={h}>{h}</option>);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Row>
           <Input l={12} value={this.state.height} onChange={this.handleChange} type='select' label="Height">
             {this.displayHeights()}
           </Input>
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  };
};

export default HeightPicker;
```

As constructed above, it's returning a blank form. If I hardcode options into my render function it works, therefore I'm assuming my issue is arising through my displayHeights function. But I also was running into some issues earlier with React Materialize and the version of React I was running -- had to downgrade versions from 16.0.0 to 15.6.2 -- so I'm wondering if it's related to that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach` in `displayHeights` method

`forEach` method does some operation on each element of array or collection, but does not return the modified element, `map` method returns the modified element after some operation

Your implemenetation has two issues

1. you are using `forEach` which does not return the modified elements
2. you did not `return` the array containing options, in your case , `heights`

The modified code block will be

```
return heights.map(function(h) {
  return(<option value={h}>{h}</option>);
});
```

Comment: Provides the same result, which is unfortunately nothing

Comment: Cool yea looks like I was missing the return in front of the heights. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should be your `displayHeights` function. Here is a [**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ecymkr)

You need to return the array back in your function and also `map` is what you should be using.

```
displayHeights(){
    let prices = this.props.prices;
    let height;
    let heights = [];
    console.log(prices);
    for (height in prices) {
      heights.push(height)
    };
    console.log(heights);
    return heights.map(function(h, i) {
      return(<option key={i} value={h}>{h}</option>);
    });
  }
```

Using `forEach`

```
let heightsJSX = [];
heights.forEach(function(h, i) {
  heightsJSX.push(<option key={i} {value={h}>{h}</option>));
});

return heights;
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency's sake, why not just `map` over the keys. Here's a one-liner.

```
displayHeight() {

    return Object.keys(this.props.prices).map(key => <option key={key} value={key}>{key}</option>);
}
```